# Password less ssh AIX Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, aix

I tried to configure password less SSH from AIX to Linux. I executed the command.

```
scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub root@10.170.163.74:/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When I execute the command and try to connect from AIX to Linux it's working. But when I restart the session and try again I'm prompted again for password. What is the correct way to configure this?

Comment: Some housekeeping script might have restored the former authorized_keys file. Consult your sysadmin before appending you pubkey to authorized_keys (not overwriting it, mind you).

Answer (score 1):

Try follow this guide step-to-step:

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

Worked for me!